# Should I leave href empty when implementing click events via jQuery?

Tags: html

Is it preferable to have `#` in a link's `href` attribute when I am implementing the `click` event via jQuery, or is it ok to leave `href` empty?

i.e.

```
<a id="myLink" href="#" />
```

vs

```
<a id="myLink" href="" />
```

When I'm doing

```
$("#myLink").on('click', function() {
   // do ajaxy stuff
});
```

Although I understand the click event could be on a span or other such element I'm interested in this case for particular best practices when using an `a` tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Links with an empty `href` attribute are valid, as explained in [RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> 4.2. Same-document References
>
> A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the current document.  In other words, an empty URI reference within a document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document, and a reference containing only a fragment identifier is a reference to the identified fragment of that document. Traversal of such a reference should not result in an additional retrieval action. However, if the URI reference occurs in a context that is always intended to result in a new request, as in the case of HTML's FORM element, then an empty URI reference represents the base URI of the current document and should be replaced by that URI when transformed into a request.

It's not really an issue significant enough to be anything more than personal preference. Personally, I'd go with a third option:

```
<a id="myLink" href="<url>" />
```

...where `<url>` is the url of my ajax request. Obviously that introduces a step in jQuery:

```
$("#myLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   url = $(this).attr("href");

   // do ajaxy stuff
});
```

...but I find it a bit more convenient than hardcoding the url in Javascript, it makes sense semantically (checking your code couple of years after you wrote it, the url will be were you'll first look for it - probably). It's also a neat trick if you have a few simplistic ajax-y links that do more or less the same thing. Consider this example:

```
<a class="ajax" href="<url1>">
<a class="ajax" href="<url2>">
<a class="ajax" href="<url3>">

$("a.ajax").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
          
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: interesting I never thought to add the url and then get it via ajax

Comment: @dreza One thing to keep in mind is that you _must_ call `event.preventDefault()` prior to doing anything else, or else the browser will execute the link normally. See: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Thanks I had just realised that after trying your suggestion.  Works well

Comment: +1 @dreza This solution also allows you to degrade gracefully if the user has JavaScript disabled. For ex. in your server-side code, you can check if the `X-Requested-With` header is set to `XMLHttpRequest`. If not, you can redirect to a page instead of doing the "ajaxy" stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it'll make a huge difference most of the time. If there's no real link, you might also consider using a span instead of an a tag.

I've seen something like this as well:

```
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:void(0)" />
```

See this page for examples: http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2008/09/30/javascript-in-lt-a-gt-tags-vs-javascript-void-0.aspx

Additionally, it would be a good idea to run the html through a validator to check for any potential problems.

Comment: Cheers.  Most of the times it is a link but I guess good to consider for those when it's not a direct url linkage

Answer (score 3):

Yannis' answer is a good one, but I still don't know why anyone would need to use <a href...> tags for events at all. You can use pretty much any tag you can throw an id into for events, thereby removing the whole 'href="" is legal' discussion or employing code to prevent the link being followed.

On the other hand, if it's a link then use <a href="...">

Comment: Cheers Ian.  Yes in this case I was interested in best practices around using a tags as it's intention is to be a link